# Create new sheets based on the date in an existing sheet...column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Master sheet with a date column.
The data in the master sheet has duplicate dates. Meaning for what ever month we are taling about I can have 07/01/2010 as many as 100 times, or as few as 2 times.

What I want to do is sift through the date column and create new sheets based on the date (day) in that column, but I only want unique values.

So I have multiple examples of creating a new sheet in VBA, that's not my issue. It's generating the unique list to get the sheets created is where I am having a problem.

```
Sub Add_Sheets()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("MasterSheet"))
WS.Name = 1  '<-- Want to call something so as to get the day from Master dynamically'
End Sub
```

This gets me my unique dates, but not days list:

```
Sub UniqueList()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sheets As Worksheet
Set sheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
lastrow = sheets.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
sheets.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=sheets.Range("G2"), Unique:=True 'dont prefer this but it works.
End Sub
```

So I'm open to suggestion.
Recently started this project, so not to far into it to redo all of it. Needs to be VBA, so users can just click buttons.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The simplest way is to iterate on cells of the date column, create a name string such as `"WS_" & cell.Text` and check if a sheet with this name already exists, create it of not. Did I miss something?

Comment: That's it exactly, just looking for some sample code to hel me get there....Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function getSheetByName(sh As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getSheetByName = Worksheets(sh)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set getSheetByName = Nothing
End Function

Sub CreateSheetsByUniqueDate()
   Dim cell As Range, name As String
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   For Each cell In Worksheets("MasterSheet").UsedRange.Columns(3).Cells ' <~~ set to your date column
       name = "WS_" & Format(cell.Text, "dd")
       If getSheetByName(name) Is Nothing Then Worksheets.Add().name = name
   Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: gets an error here: For each cell in Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("A:A")    I updated to "C:C" as that is my date column, but just errors....

Comment: @okmred ok it is because worksheet name do not accept the "/" character in the name. Try to change the format of the date column to avoid /.

Comment: can we not use Day() in the range some how??

Comment: What is the name you want to give to the new ws according to the date? can you give a precise example please?

Comment: I want to use the date of the day. So in the column I have:07/01/2010  I want to have that equal sheet 1, if I have 07/12/2010....I want that to equal sheet 12....

Comment: Ah, so it means you want to ignore the month and year? the edit does that.

Comment: But this means if you have two entries with same day but different month or year, they will map to the same worksheet. You know what you are doing, I guess.

Comment: new issue...maybe, my dates start on the 2nd row.  (I'm doing this by month, so that part shouldn't matter).

Comment: @okmred If you have difficulties to modify the code to take into account that it starts at A2, dont hesitate to tell me :)

Comment: All I ended up doing was adding a line to delete the tabs I didn/t want. But I'd be interested in seeing how to change the starting point of the column. Thanks

Comment: You can add an additional test like `If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then ...` before creating the Worksheet.